# Push and Pop navigation from tab bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

Hello,
I'm new in flutter , 
I created a login form in `main.dart` page after tapping the `logout` button it will open the Tabbar with 2 children's `Tab1.dart` and `Tab2.dart` .
In `Tab2.dart`,  I have logout button and on logout click I just to navigate to my login page but I tried and it shows a black screen to me.

```
//main.dart
 child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TabBarPage()));
                  },

                )
```

```
//Tab2.dart

class Tab2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("PROFILE"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Logout',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.settings_power,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are pushing to `TabBarPage` and you are poping `Tab2`. Something missing here.

Comment: Yes, I'm not getting how to pop the ```TabBarPage``` please help me out @Blasanka

Comment: Thats strange your code working for me. Where in main.dart dart you have that button

Comment: You shouldnt do it inside `MaterialApp`, rather a `Stateless` or `Stateful` widget

Comment: I implemented this code inside ```StateLess```  .....

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace your `main.dart` code with below code

```
child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text(
                "Login",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TabBarPage()))
              },

            )
```

Comment: Still not getting. Is there any changes in ```Tab2.dart```?

Comment: No everything is fine in the other class :) it's a strange

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `RaisedButton` use `FloationActionButton` and 
give `heroTag="btn1"`. It must solve your problem

```
FloatingActionButton(
heroTag="btn1",
                  child: Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TabBarPage()));
                  },
                )
```